# How to unlink AdWords account created within My Client Center?

Tags: google, google-ads, accounts

I have an AdWords My Client Center (MCC) that I log into. I am the only one that can log into the MCC. Within the MCC, I have 3 linked Adwords Accounts. These are each separate, standalone AdWords accounts that were created by clients.

During some testing I was doing, within my MCC, I clicked **+Create Account** and chose **Adwords** in order to add a new account to my MCC. *Note: I am not linking an existing standalone account to my MCC. I am creating a new account within my MCC.* I name this account **Test Client 1**.

Now that I have created my new account, I want to delete it because I only made it as a test. If I go to Arrange **Accounts > Unlink Account(s)** I get the following error:

> This account must have at least one active user before you can unlink it.  Please invite a user to the account with "Administrative Access" or link  the account to another MCC before unlinking.

So how exactly do I add an active user to this account, **Test Client 1**? When I click the account and go into the details of that account, I do not see anywhere in the interface where you can add a user to the account.

If I go into my MCC preferences, here there is an Account Access page, which allows me to add a new user to the ENTIRE MCC account. But this gives the user access to the ENTIRE MCC. I don't want that. I just want to add a user to this one **Test Client 1** account I made. There doesn't appear to be a way to give a user access only to a specific account within the MCC.

Just for the heck of it, I went ahead and invited a new user to the MCC with full Administrative Access. Now I have my login and this other login (a dummy @gmail address I made) that can access my MCC. There still does not appear to be a way to add a user to the **Test Client 1** account I made so I can unlink it.

What am I missing here? How do I add a new active user to the **Test Client 1** account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is been asked in at least threads in the Google Adwords help forums.  [1](https://www.en.adwords-community.com/t5/Basics-for-New-Advertisers/How-to-unlink-an-adwords-account-from-my-MCC/td-p/69934), [2](https://www.en.adwords-community.com/t5/Members-lounge/How-to-unlink-accounts-from-MCC/td-p/324759), [3](https://www.en.adwords-community.com/t5/Basics-for-New-Advertisers/MCC-Delete-Create-Account/td-p/64504).

The most helpful post in all of that is from [sharepower](https://www.en.adwords-community.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/36686):

> the only way to do it, it to create a new gmail account. Give this account admin access to Adwords. Only then will you be able to remove from MCC. Once removed from MCC, the Adwords account can be cancelled. I agree that its bizarre that Google does not allow removal of useless accounts in MCC

Here are the instructions for [cancelling an AdWords account](http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2424604&rd=1).